# `against payment in New York,New York` in one sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

source:
http://www.fanniemae.com/resources/file/ir/pdf/stock-info/series_s_12062007.pdf

The  Underwriters  expect  to  deliver  the  Preferred  Stock  in  book-
entry  only  form  through  the  facilities
of  The  Depository  Trust  Company against payment in New York, New York, on or about December 11, 2007.

[image]

There are two New York in this long sentence.

`against payment in New York, New York, on or about December 11, 2007.`

Can it be written as

`against payment in New York on or about December 11, 2007.`  ?

Comment: The duplicated *New York*s eliminate any possible ambiguity. *New York, New York* is the city of New York in the state of New York; bare *New York* might be parsed as "anywhere in the state of New York", which might be inconvenient for the payee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*New York, New York* defines that payment was to be made in **the city of New York** in "the state of New York", rather than anywhere in New York, which could mean either the city or the state.